# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client with expressjs

Tags: javascript, express

I want to redirect to another page after successful login , but it show me this message "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", i know i should have place the res.redirect somewhere else but i really struggling with this one

```
router.get('/login',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('login')
})
router.post('/login',(req,res)=>{
    user.findOne({
        where: {
            userName : req.body.userName
        }
    })
    .then(userInfo=>{
        if(userInfo){
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password,userInfo.password)){
                const token = jwt.sign(userInfo.dataValues,process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
                    expiresIn:1440
                })

               res.send(token)
               res.redirect('/home')

            }

            else {
                res.status(400).json({error:'user doesnt exist'})
            }


        }
    }
    )
})
```

Comment: Could be this line `res.send(token)` before the redirect. Maybe there's another way to do this? Is it possible to do this after?

Answer (score 1):

[`res.redirect`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) is just sugar for setting the a redirect status to `302` and adding a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header. You could probably just change this to:

```
res.setHeader('Location', '/home');
res.send(token);
```

---

Is `res.send(token)` really what you want to be doing? Seems to me like you'd want to be attaching a `Set-Cookie` header in the `/login` response. So maybe instead you do:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}`);
res.redirect('/home');
```

---

Or maybe your server should not be handling the redirect at all? If you're sending the token back to the client, maybe your client is responsible for attaching the token to your [document cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), and then performing the redirect client-side?

```
/* This code is run in the browser after you receive the token, not the server */

document.cookie = `token=${token}`;
window.location.href = '/home';
```

Comment: thank youu !!!! its working now , i used the second option , meanwhile the token i want to store it in local storage

Comment: You may want to consider using `document.cookie` - this value is automatically attached to your request and can be read by the server.

Comment: Thank youuu !!! i cannot sincerely express how i'm happy i'm right now , thank you for helping , its a joy seeing people helping each others